# Sketching a graph from differential equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm currently confused with the explanation for question 13b. Wouldn't the tangent for e^(-x^2-y^2) always be negative since no matter what x and y is. Since it would always be squared into a positive number and converted into a negative number with the minus signs. Therefore, it would provide a graph that looks like y=e^-x. Therefore, when the x variable in front is bigger than zero, wouldn't y' be negative? Since positive times negative is a negative? I don't understand what I'm missing here.

[image]

Comment: The exponential function is always positive regardless of $x$ or $y$. The $x$ term in front of $x e^{-x^2-y^2}$ determines positive or negative.

Comment: @Moo can you please explain why the exponential function is always positive. Are you talking about the y value of the y axis or the tangent?

Comment: @NLT a negative exponent means a reciprocal, not a negative value. $e^{-5}=1/(e^5)$, and both are positive. The exponential function is *always* positive for real inputs; its real-valued range is from arbitrarily close to zero to infinity

Comment: @NLT: What FShrike said - you are confusing a negative exponent with a negative value.